# MySQL Fetch Rows Which Contains SUB-STRING of GIVEN SIRING

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch all mySQL rows which contains **SUB-STRING** of **GIVEN SIRING**. In my case I have a list of frererred countries in a variable **$pref_country**. I wanto to slect the rows from MySQL where **country** contain a **SUB-STRING** in **$pref_country**

See my example below -

```
$pref_country = 'AU-Australia,CA-Canada,ES-Spain,GB-United Kingdom';
$rowRes = mysqli_query($mydb, "SELECT * FROM `proxylist`  WHERE `country` LIKE `%$pref_country%`");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rowRes)) {
    echo $row ['country'] . '<br/>';    
    }
```

| SL_INDEX | IP_PORT | COUNTRY_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100002 | IP:PORT | AU-Australia |
| 100003 | IP:PORT | CA-Canada |
| 100004 | IP:PORT | FR-France |
| 100005 | IP:PORT | AU-Australia |
| 100006 | IP:PORT | ES-Spain |
| 100007 | IP:PORT | GB-United Kingdom |
| 100008 | IP:PORT | ES-Spain |
| 100009 | IP:PORT | US-United States |

Comment: Split the string into individual values and use `IN`

Comment: `.. WHERE FIND_IN_SET(country_name, $pref_country)`

Comment: I am new in MySQL. Can you please write the full MySQL query?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommendations:

- Use the `IN()` predicate, not `LIKE`. `IN()` compares to a list of discrete values, not a substring. The Substring method will have bad performance, because it cannot use an index.
- Use bound parameters.
- Split your string into an array, and bind the individual values as parameters. You need as many parameter placeholders as the number of elements in the array.

Here's a way to write the code:

```
$pref_country = 'AU-Australia,CA-Canada,ES-Spain,GB-United Kingdom';

$params = explode(',', $pref_country);

$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?');
$types = str_repeat('s', count($params));

$stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `proxylist`  WHERE `country` IN ($placeholders)");

$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row ['country'] . '<br/>';    
    }
```

(I have not run this to test it. It is only for example purposes. If there's anything you don't understand, I suggest reading documentation for the respective functions I used is your next step.)

Comment: Yes. It is working perfectly. Thanks a lot friend !!!